# Struggling to get @font-face custom webfont working

Tags: html, css, fonts

Downloaded a web font to use from Creative Market and trying to implement but just doesn't seem to be working (using Chrome but also checking Safari).

Edit: Have tested the full URL so font definitely in the right place.
URL to site: https://helloarchie.co/

These are in the same CSS file, this right at the top:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'TP';
  src: url('Think-Pink-Regular.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */;
  src: url('Think-Pink-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
}
```

And this:

```
h6.categor-y3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.6em; 
  letter-spacing: 2px; 
  font-family: 'TP', Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

The fonts are definitely inside the same folder as the CSS and are named correctly.

Comment: Try a slash before the url? `url('/Think-Pink-Regular.woff')`

Comment: That's not the font, the font should look like this - 
https://creativemarket.com/VladCristea/1782154-Think-Pink-Handwritten-Font-Logos

Comment: Tried the slash, but didn't work. :(

Answer (score 0):

The fonts are in the same folder as your CSS. Therefore your relative paths to them are correct. However, the fonts can't be loaded due to a [CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) policy problem.

The hostname of your website is [helloarchie.co](http://helloarchie.co) while the CSS is loaded from [helloarchie-helloarchie.netdna-ssl.com](http://helloarchie-helloarchie.netdna-ssl.com) and so are the fonts.

Now you have several options to solve this:

1. If you have access to the webserver of [helloarchie-helloarchie.netdna-ssl.com](http://helloarchie-helloarchie.netdna-ssl.com) you can add CORS Policy rules in order to allow the sharing of fonts. Please refer <kbd>**[Here](https://zinoui.com/blog/cross-domain-fonts)**</kbd>).
2. If you do not have access to the webserver, the easiest solution would be to move the font to [helloarchie.co](http://helloarchie.co) and call it from there.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've amended the URLs now and added the code into my .htaccess but to no avail! It still doesn't work. >_<

Comment: @KayeHuett Works from my perspective: [image](https://imgur.com/a/AZ1TR) - Try to force a reload by hitting `CTRL + F5`

Comment: How bizarre, what browser is that? I've tried purging the cache and everything, does not show up for me. :/

Comment: Ah, working on safari now but not chrome. 1 down at least!

Comment: I am on Google Chrome 63 right now. Just tested on Firefox as well. Works on both. Try using Incognito mode in chrome to make sure its not your cache.

Comment: Doesn't work in incognito for me either, how bizarre. :/

Comment: Can you check your developer tools for any errors? (`CTRL + SHIFT + I` - go to `console` - then reload)

Comment: Ah yes exactly what you said. Will have to look again, I did add the code from the CORS site into my htaccess but obviously isn't accepting it.
https://imgur.com/a/1I919

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163495/discussion-between-kaye-huett-and-nulldev).